# Need example code for wp_playlist_shortcode

Tags: wordpress, audio, shortcode, playlist

I trying to use wp_playlist_shortcode for creating playlist with audio-files from all blog posts. 
In official documentation i saw this parameter:

> 'ids'
>   (array) Create a playlist out of these explicit attachment IDs. If empty, a playlist will be created from all $type attachments of $id. Default empty.

I trying this code, and its doesn't working:

```
$attch_id = array('76', '73', '70', '67');
wp_playlist_shortcode( array( 'ids' => '$attch_id' );
```

How to create playlist with audio-files from all blog posts? Now i use this code, but it is a not playlist.

```
$audios = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => null, 'post_mime_type' => 'audio/mpeg' );
                        $attachments = get_posts( $audios );
                        if ($attachments) {
                            foreach ( $attachments as $post ) { 
                                setup_postdata($post);
                                $media_url = $post->guid;
                                $media_title = $post->post_title;
                                echo wp_audio_shortcode( array( 'src' => $media_url) );
                                echo '<p>' . $media_title . '</p>';
                                // print_r($media_url);
                            }
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You have found solution here...
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141766/making-audio-playlist-with-external-audio-files

Comment: Too much superfluous code, and doesn't working `echo do_shortcode('[playlist type="audio" current="no" tracklist="yes" tracknumbers="no" images="no" artist="no"]
  [trac title="Davenport Blues" src="/wp-content/uploads/Ballada-o-korotkoj-shee-novyj-zvuk-Vladimir-Vysotskij.mp3"]
  [trac title="Dixie Blues" src="/wp-content/uploads/beep1.mp3"]
[/playlist]');`